# A Fixed-Point Function Problem

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I was asked what is the fixed point for the following function?
$g(x) = 2sin(\pi x) + x = 0$ between $[1,2]$

because $g(x) = 2sin(\pi x) + x = 0$ doesn't map, I rewrote $g(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\pi}sin^{-1}(\frac{-x}{2})$. However,this choice of g(x) doesn't map either unless I rewrite $g(x)$ as $g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}(sin^{-1}(\frac{-x}{2})$+$2\pi$). Can someone please tell me where the $+2\pi$ step comes from.

Comment: Please state your question more correctily. $2\sin(\pi x)+x=0$ is not a function, but an equation. If you are looking for fixed points of $g(x)=2\sin(\pi x)+x$, then why not simply solve $g(x)=x$, or $\sin(\pi x)=0$?

Comment: Per the comment of @Lazy, more formally $x = g(x) = 2\sin(\pi x) + x \implies 2\sin(\pi x) = 0 \iff \sin(\pi x) = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

The fixed points of $g(x)=x+ 2 \sin(\pi x)$ are the solutions of the equation $g(x)=x \Leftrightarrow \sin(\pi x) = 0$, which are given by
$$
\pi x = k \pi, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
So, $g$ has two fixed points in the interval $[1,2]$, namely $x=1$ and $x=2$.